# How do I create an entrypoint in a custom location and activate its virtual environment when executed?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've searched, but either I'm phrasing the question wrong, or it's an anti-pattern.

While I'm not new to python, I've only ever hacked on existing packages.

I'm working on a package that will only be run from wherever its repository has been cloned. I can use `pip install -e .` during development and `pip install .` once it's working the way I want.

I'm using a virtual environment, so I don't pollute my namespace, but I want to be able to run my various entrypoints without having first to activate it.

`pip install` installs those entrypoints in `venv/bin`; thus, when I want to change to that directory while doing something else, I have to run `. venv/bin/activate && entrypoint-alpha`.

I've written a script to do that in a `bin` directory at the top level of the repository. However, I just spent an hour trying to figure out why something needed to be fixed when I had just forgotten to include the new entrypoint in my script.

Is there a way to tell `pip install` to install the entrypoints in this `bin` directory instead of `venv/bin` and have the package activate the virtual environment when it's run?

**Edit**: I didn't explain myself well enough. To demonstrate what I mean, what I want to do is have a one-time (per cloned instance) installation command. I don't have a problem manually activating the virtual environment here. It's after the initial installation that I want to be able to just run the various endpoints directly, without having to remember to activate the virtual environment.

It's a personal project, no one else is going to be using it.

Installation:

```
git clone <git-url>
cd newinstance
python -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install .
```

This is all fine. But the entrypoints are installed in `venv/bin`. When I come back in a new session I'd like to be able to just run the entrypoint without having to remember to activate the virtual environment.

```
<after logging in again>
cd newinstance
bin/entrypoint-alpha
```

- Can I change the installation of those entrypoints to `bin` in the top-level of the repository?
- Can I modify my script (**not venv**) to activate the virtual environment if it's not already active?

Comment: Part of the virtual environment is the very Python implementation used to execute the script, not just the collection of 3rd-party packages installed in the virtual environment to support the script. You might have a *separate* installed that creates the necessary virtual environment before using it to execute pip-install your actual script, though.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do what venv does already. Work with it, and look into "activate_this.py" But yes, you can tell it what to call the folder. But venv gets to decide the layout within its folder.

Comment: I added to my question.